# How to find disabled azure services in azure devops project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We can disable azure devops services form UI

Is there any API available to GET the info about enabled / disabled services ?

[image]

Like in above image boards is disabled , Can I find this info using API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an feature in Project Settings.
I checked the related [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/project?view=azure-cli-latest) for Team Projects, however I did not find any available interface can list the info about enabled / disabled services, also no available interface to enabled / disabled services.

So, I think your question is more like a feature request. I recommend that you can report the feature request to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).

**[UPDATE]**

I found below API from the **Network** logs of the web browser (press **`F12`**). I have tested this API on my side, it should be the one you are looking for.

- **Request URI:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Organization_name}/_apis/FeatureManagement/FeatureStatesQuery/host/project/{Project_id}?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

- **Request Body:**

```json
{
    "featureIds": [
        "ms.vss-work.agile",  // Boards
        "ms.vss-code.version-control",  // Repos
        "ms.vss-build.pipelines",  // Pipelines
        "ms.vss-test-web.test",  // Test Plans
        "ms.feed.feed"  // Artifacts
    ],
    "featureStates": {},
    "scopeValues": {
        "project": "{Project_id}"
    }
}
```

- **Response Body:**

```json
{
    "featureIds": [
        "ms.vss-work.agile",
        "ms.vss-code.version-control",
        "ms.vss-build.pipelines",
        "ms.vss-test-web.test",
        "ms.feed.feed"
    ],
    "featureStates": {
        "ms.vss-work.agile": {
            "featureId": "ms.vss-work.agile",
            "scope": {
                "userScoped": false,
                "settingScope": "project"
            },
            "state": "disabled"
        },
        "ms.vss-code.version-control": {
            "featureId": "ms.vss-code.version-control",
            "scope": null,
            "state": "enabled"
        },
        "ms.vss-build.pipelines": {
            "featureId": "ms.vss-build.pipelines",
            "scope": null,
            "state": "enabled"
        },
        "ms.vss-test-web.test": {
            "featureId": "ms.vss-test-web.test",
            "scope": null,
            "state": "disabled",
            "reason": "\"Test Plans\" is off because the \"Boards\" feature is off. In order to manage \"Test Plans\", you must turn on \"Boards\".",
            "overridden": true
        },
        "ms.feed.feed": {
            "featureId": "ms.feed.feed",
            "scope": null,
            "state": "enabled"
        }
    },
    "scopeValues": {
        "project": "{Project_id}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right name of the features are:

```
ms.vss-build.pipelines  [Azure Pipelines]
ms.vss-test-web.test [Test Plans]
ms.vss-work.agile [Azure Boards]
ms.vss-code.version-control [Azure Repos]
ms.azure-artifacts.feature [Azure Artifacts]
```